# AEM SlingAuthenticator Exclusion list

Tags: authentication, aem, sling

I am creating a exclusion list in org.apache.sling.engine.impl.auth.SlingAuthenticator , `sling.auth.requireemnts` to allow the js and css for a `shared link functionality`[functionality:allows me to share the link to others and others clink on the link and go to the asset. without allowing those css and js files for unauthenticated user the styles are nor rendering.]

My problem is I wanted allow the entire `libs\clientlibs\granite` folder, or I have to exclude each file with one exclusion list which is adding number of values in `sling.auth.requirements` like a regex `libs\clientlibs\granite\*` , but it is not working like that.Can somebody please help me. I looked around and searched for this solution and worked on it on my local it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

I would not suggest excluding paths because it may cause security issues for your application going forward.

Assuming `share links` is a page on publish instance where you want to allow anonymous access.

Use CUG. Refer https://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/6-3/sites/administering/using/closed-user-groups.html

You site structure should be something like this.

```
|site
|| non secure section
||| share page
|| secure section 1 (apply ACL on this page)
||| child pages are secure automatically
|| secure section 2 (apply ACL on this page)
||| child pages are secure automatically
```